# General Solution for Simple Integral

Tags: integration

I want to solve the following integral:

$$\int\!x e^{3x-1}\,dx$$

I know the solution is $$\frac{1}{9}e^{3x-1}(3x-1)$$ but what is the systematic rule to get there?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with integration by parts?

Comment: Integration by parts, mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard thing to use is **integration by parts**. Let $u=x$ and $dv=e^{3x-1}\,dx$.

Then $du=dx$ and $v$ (by integration) can be taken to be $\frac{1}{3}e^{3x-1}$. We have 
$$\int u\,dv=uv-\int v\,du,$$
which in this case yields
$$\frac{x}{3}e^{3x-1}-\int \frac{1}{3}e^{3x-1}\,dx.$$
Integrate. We arrive at 
$$\frac{x}{3}e^{3x-1}-\frac{1}{9}e^{3x-1}+C.$$
This can be simplified in various ways.

**Remark:** Integration by parts is the standard tool for relatives of your problem, like $\int x\cos(5x)\,dx$, or $\int x^2 e^{2x-17}\,dx$, or $\int x^2\ln x\,dx$. After a while one learns how to spot good candidates for this method. It is *not* a universal tool. For example, $\int xe^{-x^2}\,dx$, which kind of looks like your problem, is best found  by letting $u=-x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $u=3x-1$, then:
$$
\int xe^{3x-1}dx=\frac{1}{9}\left(\int e^udu+\int ue^udu\right)
$$
The first integrand is easy, the second you integrate by parts on.